# How to add most recent dependencies to Android project?

Tags: android

Wants to use `RecyclerView` like described in this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html). But have problem already adding the import statement: `Can not resolve symbol 'RecyclerView'.`

[image]

Added compile statement to gradle script,

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

but Android studio says that a more recent version is available. Can this cause that import statement is not accepted?

[image]

Comment: sync your project with gradle file

Comment: Thanks, works, now import is accepted: `Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

Comment: *Can this cause that import statement is not accepted?* no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

23.1.1 is not the latest version of android support library

To get the current latest version you should use this if you're using `compileSdkVersion 23`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
```

or if you're using `compileSdkVersion 24` then use this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
```

and to get the latest version available automatically, you can use this :

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```